# retaining precision when adding 2 floats

Tags: c++, precision

When adding two floats is there a way to retain the precision. For example,
I am adding two floats, 89 and 0.00123 and storing the result in a variable. When I printed out the variable to see what it contained I got 89.0012. What happened to the last digit? Is there a way to ensure that I do not lose that extra digit.

Comment: A single float value can have so many digits of precision. No matter how you arrive at that float, whether by adding, multiplying, deleting, or subtracting, two, three, or a million of other floats, you still end up with just so many levels of precision. The End.

Comment: There is precision, and then there is number of [significant figures](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures) to be displayed. You probably want to change the latter, since default is 6

Comment: Did you know that your `float` isn't really 0.00123? That is a decimal approximation of the binary value. Talking about "the last digit" is misleading when the computer doesn't use digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::setprecision()`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {

    float x = 89;
    float y = 0.00123;

    std::cout << std::setprecision(7) << x + y << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```